plotly isosurface problem based on data size: it doesn't plot but also doesn't give an error message
I am a beginner in python and was playing around with data visualization for a task at my job. Simply, I need to visualize a cloud of 3D data points and I decided Isosurface function meets my expectation the best. I have three different data sets describing a certain flow profile around a wing that are only differentiated by their resolution.
My problem is; below code only works for the lowest resolution and as put in title for other two bigger (medium, high) resolution having datasets code neither displays an error code nor gives an interactible figure output:
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.io as pio
pio.renderers.default="browser"

file_name = "folder_path/dataset.dat"
df = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer=file_name, skiprows = 2, sep = " ", header = None, names = ["x", "y", "z", "I"])

x = df["x"]
y = df["y"]
z = df["z"]
I = df["I"]

fig = go.Figure(data = go.Isosurface(x = x, y = y, z = z, value = I,
                                      isomin = 0,
                                      isomax = 0.99,
                                      surface_count = 10,
                                      colorbar_nticks = 10,
                                      surface_fill=0.4,
                                      colorscale = 'Blackbody'))
fig.show()

The dataset is a very simple ascii file with 4 columns. Lowest resolution has 97920 rows, medium one has 498883 rows and highest one has 2883836 rows.
To further give details I attached two figures, one with a successful output from the lowest resolution dataset;
functioning isosurface output
and the other one is the result with no error message from the medium size dataset:
not functioning isosurface output
Can someone explain to me how this can be possible? And essentially how can I solve this issue?
P.S:
I tried the output formats other than html data  (i.e. the browser option), such as png, and it is exactly the same story.
I also tried to run it on different platforms like Spyder and Jupyter Lab but all give the same result.
2nd edit - 15.07.2024: I also tried the Volume() function instead of the Isosurfaces() function; it is still the same result...

Do you have any message logged in the browser console ?

Nope. There is no message.

In order to check whether the issue is caused by the data size or by something else, I would try to drop some rows for the 2 big datasets and see if at some point the figure is plotted properly, if not then the data are probably malformed.

I was just trying this. I deleted some rows from both the larger datasets until they were equal to lowest one. It produced an empty figure again.
However just to be sure I also did the same test to lowest resolution dataset and deleted just a couple of lines from it. That also produced an empty figure to my surprise. I don't understand how just deleting some lines also causes this.

I found an example with scatter_3d function, in which it doesn't plot when used with very large amount of datasets. Here is the link to that Plotly Community Forum post.
Apparently one has to go to much more powerful visualization libraries to display large datasets using Python.

Answers that rely heavily on links are discouraged for these reasons. This is particularly true in this case as the actual information discussing how to solve this issue is in another link referred to in that forum post. Please consider updating your answer so that it is more self-contained. Also, add a solution with code if you found one. Thanks

I'm not sure how can I provide a "code" for an answer that is so general as using completely new libraries. I understand the logic behind this criticism to my answer but I think this doesn't apply to this case. There's no code that can magically solve this incapability of plotly 3d data plotting functions. The answer is literally to use new libraries and utilize more powerful sources. And you can even find that in my comment, the last sentence :). I think I was commented for no reason here, this is all I wanted to highlight.
